! No podspec found for `flutter_tflite` in `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_tflite/ios`
I am using flutter_tflite: ^1.0.1 for building my app. It works on both Android phone and Simulators. But When I try to run it on Iphone simulators or build the ios app I get errors.

flutter build ios

The erros I get is
`
Running pod install...                                             361ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `camera_avfoundation` from
`.symlinks/plugins/camera_avfoundation/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `flutter_tflite` from
`.symlinks/plugins/flutter_tflite/ios`
[!] No podspec found for `flutter_tflite` in
`.symlinks/plugins/flutter_tflite/ios`

/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoap
ods/external_sources/path_source.rb:14:in `block in fetch'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoap
ods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoap
ods/external_sources/path_source.rb:11:in `fetch'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoap
ods/installer/analyzer.rb:997:in `fetch_external_source'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoap
ods/installer/analyzer.rb:976:in `block (2 levels) in fetch_external_sources'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoap
ods/installer/analyzer.rb:975:in `each'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoap
ods/installer/analyzer.rb:975:in `block in fetch_external_sources'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoap
ods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoap
ods/installer/analyzer.rb:974:in `fetch_external_sources'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoap
ods/installer/analyzer.rb:118:in `analyze'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoap
ods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoap
ods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoap
ods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoap
ods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoap
ods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoap
ods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/com
mand.rb:334:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoap
ods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55
:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.2/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

Error running pod install`

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
